# Can't get an enumerator from a SortedList

Tags: c#, sortedlist, enumerator

I have this object :

```
class Animation
    {
        //[...]
        private SortedList<int,Frame> frames = new SortedList<int,Frame>();
        private IDictionaryEnumerator frameEnumerator = null;

        //[...]

        public void someFunction() {
            frameEnumerator = frames.GetEnumerator(); //throw error
        }

        //[...]

}
```

I check msn documentation there : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.getenumerator.aspx, It look like my code is correct but VS say :

> cannot convert 
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator>'
>   to 'System.Collections.IDictionaryEnumerator'.

Comment: Why are you trying to get an enumerator, instead of just *using* it via `foreach` or similar?

Comment: It's because I want to get the current element. Frame have temporisation, after a specified delay enumerotar will go to the next one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `IDictionaryEnumerator` type is used for older non-generic collection types.  In this case you have a strongly type collection and it will instead return `IEnumerater<KeyValuePair<int, Frame>>`.  Use that type instead

```
private IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<int, Frame>> frameEnumerator = null;
```

Note: The enumerator type for `SortedList<TKey, TValue>` does indeed implement the `IDictionaryEnumerator` interface.  If you really prefer that one you can access it with an explicit cast

```
frameEnumerator = (IDictionaryEnumerator)frames.GetEnumerator();
```

I would avoid this route though.  It's better to use the strongly typed interfaces and avoid unnecessary casting in the code.

Comment: I have to wait 10min to accept the answer... dont know why but I will.

Answer (score 0):

Try to cast

```
frameEnumerator = frames.GetEnumerator() as IDictionaryEnumerator;
```

After that make sure that you check if `frameEnumerator` is null.